# Erro em PHP - Função Empty()

Tags: php, codeigniter

Tenho o seguinte erro:

```
Fatal error: Can't use method return value in write context in /home/username/public_html/Administrar/application/controllers/holerites.php on line 29
```

Segue a sequência de linhas 29 a seguir:

```
if(empty($this->input->post('periodo'))) $periodo = date("m")+1; else $periodo = $this->input->post('periodo');
if(empty($this->input->post('dataInicial'))) $data_inicial = ""; else $data_inicial = $this->input->post('dataInicial');
if(empty($this->input->post('dataFinal'))) $data_final = ""; else $data_final = $this->input->post('dataFinal');
```

Não tenho nem idéia porque, no localhost funciona mas no servidor não.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`empty`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) não é um função, é parte da linguagem (também chamado de "construtor da linguagem").

Você não pode chamar em cima de um valor ou de um retorno de função ou método, pois ela sempre espera uma referência (variável).

Esse é o comportamento esperado nas versões anteriores do php 5.5.

[Exemplo em várias versões do php](http://3v4l.org/jcoGR)

Comment: Adicionei o que eu precisava em uma variavel, e consegui verificar. $periodo   = $this->input->post('periodo');

Answer (score 5):

Com sugestão do Rray, fiz desta forma:

```
$periodo        = $this->input->post('periodo');
$dataInicial    = $this->input->post('dataInicial');
$dataFinal      = $this->input->post('dataFinal');

if(empty($periodo)) $periodo = date("m"); else $periodo = $this->input->post('periodo');
if(empty($dataInicial)) $data_inicial = ""; else $data_inicial = $this->input->post('dataInicial');
if(empty($dataFinal)) $data_final = ""; else $data_final = $this->input->post('dataFinal');
```

Answer (score 2):

Como dito pelo @rray, esse "construtor da linguagem", o `empty`, não funciona com expressões em versões anteriores ao PHP 5.5.

A minha sugestão para deixar o código simples seria essa:

```
if (! ($periodo = $this->input->post('periodo'))) {

   $periodo = date("m");
}

echo $periodo;
```

Ou então:

```
 $periodo = $this->input->post('periodo') ?: date('m');
```